# How to display viewbag alerts from controller in if statements in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, if-statement

All the alerts I am expecting to trigger within my if-statements in the controller are not working but the others without if-statements are working fine.  What can I do to get them display from the controller

Comment: People seeing this question will not have any idea what you are doing based on the description included so far in the question. Please add more details and code examples showing what you are doing. Welcome to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(string name)
{
    ViewBag.Message = string.Format("Hello {0}.\\nCurrent Date and Time: {1}", name, DateTime.Now.ToString());
    return View();
}
```